# change computed property of vue 2 to vue 3 composition api

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I am migrating my vue 2 application to vue 3. I read the computed property in vue 3 with composition api.

Here is the vue 2 computed property to provide some common data to different component. My question  is how to migrate it vue 3 computed property using composition api with getters and setters.

```
sharingDataInComponents() {
        let obj={}, objProperty = Object.defineProperty;
        // variable
        objProperty(obj, 'size'   , {get:()=>this.size});
        objProperty(obj, 'shape'  , {get:()=>this.shape});
        objProperty(obj, 'navigation'   , {get:()=>this.navigation});
        objProperty(obj, 'addBtn' , {get:()=>this.addBtn});
         // function
        objProperty(obj, 'onAddClick', {get:()=>this.onAddClick});

        return obj;
    },
```

How to migrate this? I am new to vue 3 composition api.

Answer (score 1):

Try like in following snippet:

```js
const { ref, computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup() {
    const size = ref(35)
    const shape = ref('cirlcle')
    const navigation = ref('left')
    const addBtn = ref(true)
    const onAddClick = () => {console.log('add')}
    
    const sharingDataInComponents = computed(() => {
      let obj={}, objProperty = Object.defineProperty;
        // variable
        objProperty(obj, 'size'   , {get:()=>size.value});
        objProperty(obj, 'shape'  , {get:()=>shape.value});
        objProperty(obj, 'navigation'   , {get:()=>navigation.value});
        objProperty(obj, 'addBtn' , {get:()=>addBtn.value});
         // function
        objProperty(obj, 'onAddClick', {get:()=>onAddClick});

        return obj;
    })
    
    return { size, shape, navigation, addBtn, onAddClick, sharingDataInComponents }
  }
})
app.mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3.2.29/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <div @click="sharingDataInComponents.onAddClick">
    {{ sharingDataInComponents.size }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just one query i have that can i expose computed properties as well like methods? context.expose({sharingDataInComponents})